# How to cancel ignore-certain-certificate on chrome/Mac

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, intern

I am using intern.js and selenium-grid to test my application web, when I run test in Chrome at node machine (MAC), I get this errors:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag --ignore-certificate-errors stability and security will be affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `test-type` option in then environments descriptor in your intern config:

```
// intern.js
// ...
environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome', chromeOptions: { args: [ 'test-type' ] } }
]
// ...
```